# how to remove a comma from an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried:

```
val['*'].replace(/,/g , '')
```

But i still have the `comma`

> ,Битва при реке Пэккан
>
> ,Bitka kod Baekganga
>
> ,Битва при річці Пек
>
> ,Trận Bạch Giang
>
> ,白江口之战

**UPDATE**

```
data.parse.langlinks.map(function(val){ 
   return val['*']
});
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what the value of val['*'] ?

Comment: @Kinduser I did that but I still get the comma

Comment: It does not mutate the original....

Comment: @epascarello is right, that might be the mistake, but you are not giving us enough code!

Comment: @Salketer what exactly do you want me to provide you? The values are a list of those languages as per the question above

Comment: ... 2,4K rep, total of 91 badges, over 200 questions asked and still haven't read how to make a question?

Comment: what is `val` ? if it is string , do you want to remove the comma from the string ?

Comment: And in that fiddle I see no replace line....

Comment: That code just keeps pummeling wikipedia's API... be MINIMAL

Comment: @epascarello because someone had commented on here saying to use `.substr(1)` and I have updated the jsFiddle accordingly, but now that comment is gone on here

Comment: @Salketer alright this is a minified version https://jsfiddle.net/zt3ssajd/656/ yet I see no commas, while on my real example commas appear. This is the different line on my real code  `$wikiDOM.find("#coordinates").parent().remove();
      $('#results').append('<li>' + curTitle + "<br>"  `

Comment: Trying to make us help you run a DDOS? Please remove all useless code, there should be no need for jQuery ajax calls to express the problem you are facing. Also, just as a side note, I tried console.log on that function and can't even reach to that part of the code in 3 minutes, I do not have a fast internet connection...

Comment: @Salketer why a DDOS? lol

Comment: lol, because your script makes use launch more than a hundred ajax calls...

Comment: @Salketer i'm trying to map wikipedia, anyway i did link to a minified version

Comment: Your snippet does not reproduce the error... I'm love to help but can't.

Comment: @Salketer exactly,. I did say that, i see no comma. tbh I don't even know where this comma is coming from, i am not inserting it anywhere and as you could see, there is no comma in the simplified version

Comment: You should try to narrow down the problem slimming your original code step by step. My guess is that the variable you are displaying is in fact an array, with an empty value + the correct value. This would add the comma since when arrays are stringified their values are commas seperated.

Comment: @Salketer it is indeed an array but I cannot see the empty one

Comment: @Salketer this is the line I use to get that val `data.parse.langlinks.map(function(val){ 
   return val['*']`

Comment: It is not the correct part, I am sure this one is ok... It is later when you add them to the HTML I'm sure

Comment: @Salketer this is the full line that adds it `$('#results').append('<li>' + curTitle + "<br>" + doSelect("Location").siblings('td').text() + '<br>' + d + "<br>" + data.parse.langlinks.map(function(val){ return val['*'] + "<br>" }) + '</li>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've finally been able to grab, you are using this kind of line (stripped a bit)

```
$('#results').append('<li>' + curTitle + "<br>" +   data.parse.langlinks.map(function(val){ return val['*'] + "<br>" }) + '</li>');
```

What happens is that the result from data.parse.langlinks.map is an array, and to concatenate that to the

string, its values are concatenated with the dreaded comma.

You can see by yourself using this:

```
console.log(data.parse.langlinks.map(function(val){ return val['*'] + "<br>" }).toString());
```

To fix this, you have multiple possibilities, the best is to leverage jQuery's flexible append this way:

```
$('#results').append('<li>' , curTitle , "<br>" ,   data.parse.langlinks.map(function(val){ return val['*'] + "<br>" }) , '</li>');
```

The good thing about append is that it takes unlimited amount of parameters, just as if you called it once for every param. And it also accepts array, and handle them correctly.

Comment: hey thanks, yes it does work, also didn't know I could use comma instead of the + sign

Comment: Look out, comma and + sign are two different things. It is just that we happen to be able to pass more than one argument to append()